# Line Displacement with fadein

Tags: javascript, css

I'm kind of stuck on creating a fadeIn of strings. What I want to do is have a bar appear next to a string when the user hovers over it. Like this:

```
| string
```

But the thing is, when the `|` appears, there is a displacement of the string to the right, how would I go about fixing this problem? This is my current CSS and Java code.

```
.details{
    font-size: 2.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 5em;
    /*display:none;*/
}

.line{
    border-style:solid;
    border-left: double-thick;
    border-color: #336699;
    display: none;
    margin-right: .4em;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.details').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.line').remove();
        $(this).prepend('<a class="line"></a>');
        $('.line').fadeIn(250);
    });
    $('.details').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.line').fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each row (parent element of .line and .details) is relative-positioned, try this

```
.details{
font-size: 2.1em;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 5em;
position: relative;
left: 10px; /*play with this*/
/*display:none;*/
}

.line{
border-style:solid;
border-left: double-thick;
border-color: #336699;
position: absolute; /* */
left: 0px; /* */
display: none;
margin-right: .4em;
}
```

This will push the details element 10px or however much space is needed while preventing the line element from pushing the details

Answer (score 0):

Done without any JavaScript, can you believe it?

## Fiddle

```
p::before {
    content: '|';
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -5px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 250ms;
}

p:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Ahhh, the power of CSS3